# Two sets of video controls-difficulty with getElementById / querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create two sets of play/pause controls for a video using jquery and css. The first set is on the first screen in a large size, and the second set is in a fixed location in the viewport as the user scrolls down, this is so the user can listen to the audio and operate the controls as they view the website without having to scroll to the top. When the users clicks pause, the video pauses and fades, the pause button fades, and the play button becomes full opacity, and the opposite happens when the user clicks play. I have this working for the first set in the jsfiddle and code below, however I have been trying for the past few hours to find a way to make these changes happen with both sets of controls so both sets stay in sync (ie: when one pause button fades, the one in the second set does as well) and have not been able to make much progress.

Here is a [jsfiddle (edited, was missing some css)](https://jsfiddle.net/3tLbd24d/2/) of the first set working, and the jquery:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'playing', {
  get: function() {
    return !!(this.currentTime > 0 && !this.paused && !this.ended && this.readyState > 2);
  }
})

var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"),
  pauseButton = document.getElementById("vidpause"),
  playButton = document.getElementById("vidplay");
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
function vidFade() {
  vid.classList.add("stopfade");
}


pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  vid.classList.toggle("stopfade");
  if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play();
    vidpause.classList.add("full-button");
    vidpause.classList.remove("fade-button");
    vidplay.classList.add("fade-button");
    vidplay.classList.remove("full-button");
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    vidpause.classList.add("fade-button");
    vidpause.classList.remove("full-button")
    vidplay.classList.add("full-button");
    vidplay.classList.remove("fade-button")
  }
})

playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  vid.classList.toggle("stopfade");
  if (vid.playing) {
    vid.pause();
    vidplay.classList.add("full-button");
    vidplay.classList.remove("fade-button");
    vidpause.classList.add("fade-button");
    vidpause.classList.remove("full-button");
  } else {
    vid.play();
    vidplay.classList.add("fade-button");
    vidplay.classList.remove("full-button")
    vidpause.classList.add("full-button");
    vidpause.classList.remove("fade-button")
  }
})
```

I know that getElementById will only work with one element, to get the second set working with the first, I have tried using getElementByClassName (not shown) or querySelectorAll (below).

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'playing', {
  get: function() {
    return !!(this.currentTime > 0 && !this.paused && !this.ended && this.readyState > 2);
  }
})

 var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
              function vidFade() {
                  vid.classList.add("stopfade");
              }

              var pauseButton = document.querySelectorAll(".vidpause");
              var i;
              for (i = 0; i < pauseButton.length; i++) {
              pauseButton[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                  vid.classList.toggle("stopfade");
                if (vid.paused) {
                    vid.play();
                        vidpause.classList.toggleClass("full-button");
                        vidpause.classList.remove("fade-button");
                        vidplay.classList.add("fade-button");
                        vidplay.classList.remove("full-button");
                                } 
                else {
                      vid.pause();
                          vidpause.classList.add("fade-button");
                          vidpause.classList.remove("full-button")
                          vidplay.classList.add("full-button");
                          vidplay.classList.remove("fade-button")
                        }
                                                                })
                    }


                var playButton = document.querySelectorAll(".vidplay");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < pauseButton.length; i++) {
                playButton[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                    vid.classList.toggle("stopfade");
                    if (vid.playing) {
                        vid.pause();
                            vidplay.classList.add("full-button");
                            vidplay.classList.remove("fade-button");
                            vidpause.classList.add("fade-button");
                            vidpause.classList.remove("full-button");
                    } else {
                        vid.play();
                            vidplay.classList.add("fade-button");
                            vidplay.classList.remove("full-button")
                            vidpause.classList.add("full-button");
                            vidpause.classList.remove("fade-button")
                            }
                                                                })
                }
```

When I try the above and variations of it, the chrome console gives me an error of "vidpause is undefined". I have been thinking maybe there is an issue with the order I am calling my elements in, or trying to loop the array (?) or trying to change classes while calling classes but ... I am stumped.

Any advice on this would be very helpful, I am pretty new to jquery.

Comment: Forget the video controls for a while, see instead if you can create two elements, select them both and fire an event, the same event, when either is clicked.

Comment: `vidplay` and `vidpause` do not exist `undefined`, use `pauseButton` and `playButton` instead.

Comment: A follow up to @AdrianLynch's comment. It would appear this is using [javascript, not really jQuery](https://blog.udemy.com/jquery-vs-javascript/). In order to trigger the same even using different elements using jQuery see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/J4C0814N/uatg1mjn/) it should have everything you need.

Comment: @Jake, sorry, I see now that my jsfiddle was missing some css. I've been able to get both the play and the pause button (2 elements)  in the first set to work with pausing/playing the video. What I haven't been able to do is to get the second set of controls to fade in sync with the first set. This is the URL of the updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/3tLbd24d/2/. I think that shows I've been able to achieve what you're and Adrian Lynch are suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, so it does not have the `classList` property thus the error.

You need to iterate over the list and set the property. You can also simplify the code set by adding a common class `video-play` and `video-pause` to all the play and pause buttons

```js
Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'playing', {
  get: function() {
    return !!(this.currentTime > 0 && !this.paused && !this.ended && this.readyState > 2);
  }
})

var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function vidFade() {
  vid.classList.add("stopfade");
}

function fadeInOut(fadeIn, fadeOut) {
  [].forEach.call(fadeIn, function(el) {
    el.classList.add('full-button');
    el.classList.remove('fade-button');
  });
  [].forEach.call(fadeOut, function(el) {
    el.classList.remove('full-button');
    el.classList.add('fade-button');
  });
};

var pauseButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".video-pause");
var playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".video-play");
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".video-play, .video-pause"), function(pauseButton) {
  pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    vid.classList.toggle("stopfade");
    if (vid.paused) {
      vid.play();
      fadeInOut(pauseButtons, playButtons);
    } else {
      vid.pause();
      fadeInOut(playButtons, pauseButtons);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
video#myVideo {
  transition: 1s opacity;
}
.stopfade {
  opacity: .5;
}
.vidplay {
  opacity: 0.50;
}
.vidpause {
  opacity: 1;
}
/* Play/Pause Main */

.icon-play-main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 165px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 23px 35px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ff0;
  /* #666 */
}
.icon-pause-main,
.icon-pause-main:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 14px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #ff0;
  /* #666 */
}
.icon-pause-main {
  top: 165px;
  left: 3.5px;
}
.icon-pause-main:after {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
}
/* Play/Pause bottom left */

.playpause {
  top: 230px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  x-index: 510;
}
.icon-play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 10px 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #0cf;
  /* #666 */
}
.icon-pause,
.icon-pause:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #0cf;
  /* #666 */
}
.icon-pause {
  top: 10px;
  left: 6px;
}
.icon-pause:after {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
}
.fade-button {
  opacity: 0.50;
}
.full-button {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay loop muted id="myVideo">
  <source src="http://hushhushandsecret.com/hhs/jquery/fullpagejs/imgs/flowers.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video element.
</video>

<a class="video-pause vidpause full-button" href="#"><span class="icon-pause-main"></span></a>
<a class="video-play vidplay fade-button" href="#"><span class="icon-play-main"></span></a>

<div class="playpause">
  <a class="full-button" href="#"><span class="video-pause icon-pause"></span></a>
  <a class="fade-button" href="#"><span class="video-play icon-play"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works beautifully. Is there a reason why in the second set the video-pause and video-play classes are in the <span> tag? I moved them to the <a> tag because there was some issues with the full-button now showing on the play.

A second question - when either of the controls are clicked it returns the video to the top of the screen, even when scrolled down. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @johzephine In the click handler, you need to prevent the default action

Answer (score 0):

in order to convert it to a cleaner jQuery method you will need to do the following:

Add an extra generic class to each of the video controls such as `play` and `pause`:

```
<a id="vidpause" class="full-button" href="#"><span class="icon-pause-main pause"></span></a>
<a id="vidplay" class="fade-button" href="#"><span class="icon-play-main play"></span></a>

<div class="playpause">
  <a class="full-button" href="#"><span class="icon-pause pause"></span></a>
  <a class="fade-button" href="#"><span class="icon-play play"></span></a>
</div>
```

Then use jQuery generic class selectors with `$(this)` to manipulate the video and clicked controls as necessary:

```
// create a variable for the video element
var vid = $('#myVideo');

// Function to re-uyse repeated code
// Takes a bool playing - is the video playing
// takes element clicked - the video control element clicked
function vidControls(playing, clicked){
// if the video is playing pause it
if(!playing){
    vid.get(0).pause();
    clicked.parent('a').removeClass('fade-button').addClass('full-button'); // toggle the classes
    clicked.parent('a').prev().removeClass('full-button').addClass('fade-button'); // assume pause always before play
  }else{ // otherwise play it
  vid.get(0).play();
    clicked.parent('a').removeClass('full-button').addClass('fade-button'); // toggle the classes
    clicked.parent('a').prev().removeClass('fade-button').addClass('full-button'); // assume pause always before play
  }
}

// Play button click event
$('.play').click(function(){
    // fade the video in/out as necessary
    vid.toggleClass('stopfade');
  // Re-use repeating code
  vidControls(vid.get(0).paused, $(this));
});

// Pause button click event
$('.pause').click(function(){
    // fade the video in/out as necessary
    vid.toggleClass('stopfade');
    // Re-use repeating code:
  vidControls(vid.get(0).paused, $(this)); 
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/J4C0814N/rh1m7h8m/)